# Google Colab - Install from GitHub? GLRM

Tags: python, github, google-colaboratory

My team and I are working on Colab. We would like to use the [GLRM package](https://github.com/cehorn/glrm).

Is there any way to install it directly from GitHub?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Installing anything from Github is easy using pip:

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/cehorn/GLRM.git
```

You have acces to the full command line in Google Colab, so you can install anything you want, any way you want. Just put a ! in front of any command in a cell and it is executed on the command line.

Comment: how do we iimport the package after?

Comment: Is there an answer to how the package can be imported?

Comment: Run `from glrm import GLRM`

Comment: What if we are trying to pip install a private repo?

Answer (score 2):

A good way is to clone the git hub folder like this:

```
 !git clone https://github.com/cehorn/GLRM.git
```

it wil create a folder in the /content side of drive like this:
[image]