# How can I install Github project for Google Colab?

Tags: github, pip, conda, google-colaboratory

There is a project on github called Fpocket. This project is not being installed with "pip install ...", but developers share installation commands for conda.

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install fpocket
```

I could not open the project from Google colab as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62596466/how-can-i-run-notebooks-of-a-github-project-in-google-colab) (StackOverflow)

Also solution below doesn't work (mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50850216/google-colab-install-from-github-glrm) (StackOverflow)

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/Discngine/fpocket
```

I am getting an error like

> ERROR: File "setup.py" not found for legacy project
> git+https://github.com/Discngine/fpocket.

Github project link is [here](https://github.com/Discngine/fpocket)

How can I use this project in Google Colab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install fpocket with the following set of commands:

WARNING: initial run will take about 5 minutes or so to install conda and fpocket.

```
!pip install -q condacolab

import condacolab
condacolab.install()

!conda config --add channels conda-forge
!conda install fpocket
```

then try running

```
!fpocket | head -10
```

to check the installation, in my case I get

```
***** POCKET HUNTING BEGINS ***** 
! Invalid pdb name given.

:||: fpocket 4.0 :||:
        
Mandatory parameters : 
    fpocket -f --file pdb or cif file                                      
    [ fpocket -F --fileList fileList ]
```

which makes me believe that fpocket is installed is ready to go.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://github.com/conda-incubator/condacolab#usage), the default installation is Mambaforge, so there shouldn't be any need to manually add **conda-forge** channel. And one can use `mamba install fpocket` for faster installation.